# scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation not getting called

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to perform some action when `scrollview` finish scrolling, so I wrote that acton in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` delegate method. It is working fine when rect is not visible and scrollview scrolls to new rect. But when rect is already visible `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` method will not be called and so the method written inside `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` will not get called. But I want to call that action, can anyone knows how to call that method when scrollview finish scrolling?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I think this one catches a few people out. What actually happens is that `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` is only called if you explicitly invoke either the `setContentOffset:animated:` or the `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` methods.

As the [UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) states:

> **Discussion**
>   The scroll view calls this method at the end of its
>   implementations of the setContentOffset:animated: and
>   scrollRectToVisible:animated: methods, *but only if animations are
>   requested*.

So what to do? Well, let's not forget that typically the offsetting of content data in a scroll view is not animated. Rather, it is the result of continuously updating the `contentOffset` value. So, you could possibly trigger your method based upon a specific `contentOffset` using the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method.

Alternatively, if it is something to be done after every scroll gesture - specifically, after the private `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer` - then you could do it in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`:

> **Discussion**
>  The scroll view calls this method ***when the scrolling
>   movement comes to a halt***. The decelerating property of UIScrollView
>   controls deceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Implement both `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging:`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // User lifted finger while scrolling
    [self doPostScrollAction];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if(!decelerate)
    {
        // User lifted finger after stopping scrolling
        [self doPostScrollAction];
    }
}
```